# How do you display an image on a website from a database using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been trying to make a visual database website that displays an image, its name, brand, etc, in a table. I've managed to get most of it working but got stuck trying to find out how to display images. For some reason the only image that works is the first row but everything after that shows no image. My current code is:

```
    function retrieveItems(){

    var Tablerow = document.getElementById("table");
    Tablerow.class = "w3-ul w3-card-4";
    Tablerow.style = "background-color: #202020";

    var row = document.getElementById("row");
    row.style = "height: 220px";

    var tableData = document.getElementById("tableData");
    tableData.class = "w3-large w3-left";

    var actionButton = document.getElementById("editButton");
    actionButton.innerHTML = "Edit";

    var table = document.getElementById("row");
    var clone = table.cloneNode(true);

for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; ++i){

    document.getElementById("itemname").innerHTML = "Item: " + item.name,
    document.getElementById("itembrand").innerHTML = "Brand: " + item.brand,
    document.getElementById("itemcategory").innerHTML = "Category: " + item.category

}

    storage.ref(item.category + '/' + item.number + '.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        document.getElementById("itemImage").src = url;
    });

table.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }


    function createTable() {
        var Tableclassrow = document.getElementById("classrow");
        Tableclassrow.class = "row";
        Tableclassrow.style = "background-color: #202020";
    }

    function createRow() {


    }
```

I'm very new to JavaScript so there's probably a billion errors but all I need is to be able to see images. There is a bit more code I haven't included because I don't think it's needed but if you'd like to see it I can post it.

EDIT: HTML Section

```
            <div class="gtco-tab-content-wrap">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <p align=left>
                           <label>Select Category *</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="category"                                 onblur="getSubcategoryArray()">
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
                        </p><p align=left>
                            <label>Select Subcategory</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="subcategory">
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
                        </p><p align=left>
                            <label>Item Number/Reference</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="itemnumberlookup">

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center"><br>
                        <br><button class="btn-lg btn-primary btn" onclick="searchDatabase()"><font size="5">Search</font></button>
                        </div>
                    </div><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tableclass" class="gtco-tab-content-wrap">
             <div id="tableclass2" class= "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <div id="classrow"><br>
                    <font size="5" id="databaselabel"></font><br>
                    <hr id="divider" style="height:px;border:none;color:none;background-color:none;"/><br>
                        <ul id="table">
                            <li class="w3-bar" id="row">
                            <img class="w3-bar-item" style="width:315px" id="itemImage">

                            <span onclick="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" 
                            id="editButton"><font size="4"></font></span>
                            <div id="tableData" class= "w3-large w3-left">
                                    <p align="left">
                        <span id="itemname"></span><br>
                        <span id="itembrand"></span><br>
                        <span id="itemnumber"></span><br>
                        <span id="itemcategory"></span><br>
                        <span id="itemdiscount"></span><br>
                        <span id="itemexpiration"></span><br>
                        <span id="itemterms"></span><br>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<canvas>`, if HTML 5 is an option - see [MDN Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: I'm not sure if <canvas> would work as I need to use an image of something such as a car rather than some text or gradient

Answer (score 0):

The only `src` you're setting is `document.getElementById("itemImage").src = url`, so only the first element of your DOM `<img id="itemImage">` will get a src and will load and display the image.

The first thing to know is `id` have to be unique in your DOM. Otherwise `document.getElementById("yourId")` will always returns the same node. When you make a table, you have to identify each row with a unique id, like `item-1`, `item-2`, `item-3`, etc..., and then each cell of your table will have a class name like `itemImage`, `itemBrand`, etc...

Then, you can access the image of item n°25 with `document.getElementById('item-25).getElementsByClassName('itemImage')[0]`

So assuming your code, the solution should be something like this :

```
var table = document.getElementById("row");

itemArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var clone = table.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "item-" + item.number
    clone.getElementsByClassName('itemname')[0].innerHTML = "Item: " + item.name,
    clone.getElementsByClassName('itembrand')[0].innerHTML = "Brand: " + item.brand,
    clone.getElementsByClassName('itemcategory')[0].innerHTML = "Category: " + item.category
    storage.ref(item.category + '/' + item.number + '.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        clone.getElementsByClassName('itemImage')[0].src = url;
    });
    table.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'm getting an error that reads "TypeError: table.cloneNode is not a function" not sure why as it should be working! Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your element doesn't exists yet. add `console.log(table)` after initialization of variable `table` to see if it's defined

Comment: Please could you add the HTML markup of your table in your post?

Comment: Ok so, first of all change `id="itemname"`, `id="itembrand"`, etc..., by `class="itemname"`, `class="itembrand"`, etc...  in your HTML. Then `console.log(table)` after initialization in JS and check the value in your browser console.

Comment: ah, I overlooked that completely. It fixed the error. When I added the console.log(table) to the JS and checked the console I get this error: "Table is not defined" (Then directs me to the line I added).